# Is it possible to have 2 mouses connected to each PC ( + 2monitors) while each works on 1 monitor

Tags: desktop-computer

I have 2 monitors and 2 mouses connected to my pc. Is it somehow possible to use each mouse on each monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. You can't have multiple cursors natively in Windows 10, but you can use a 3rd party tool, like [PluralInput](https://pluralinput.com/), which allows you to add more cursors (given you have enough mice connected, of course) these do have their own limits, though. I don't know if this is still true today, but a long time ago when I used PluralInput it didn't play nicely with first person games, causing the camera to move sporadically.
About the whole "1 mouse on each monitor" I don't know how you'd exactly be able to do it, but you could probably find a setting to do something like that. As said, I have not used tools like this in a very long time, so I don't know if they have these features now.

*Note: PluralInput is undergoing some driver problems right now so I would wait a little bit before you try it out.*